# Проблема в кодировке

Tags: кодировка, php

Был сайт в windows-1251, возникло задача перевести его в utf 8. Я сменил кодировки которые задаются у сайта. Затем в Notepad++ заменил кодировку в файлах на Utf-8 (без BOM).
Залил на сервер, посмотрел, почти все страницы сайта отображаются хорошо, но почти.. Некоторые отображали кракозябры, решением этой проблемы стало пересоздать файл. И всё заработало. Кроме одного файла он всё равно отображает Рђ Сѓ РЅР°СЃ РїРµСЂРµСЂС‹РІ!!!

Что можно ещё предпринять? Что бы исправить эту проблему.

Comment: Похоже, кто-то браузеру говорит, что содержимое -- в windows-1251. А там -- utf8

Comment: Всё вроде в utf-8 перевёл

Comment: Посмотрите сниффером (напр. wireshark). Если сайт в инете, можете дать ссылку.

Comment: http://new.lokki.su/ - Title кракозябры пишет

Comment: Response Headers

Content-Type:text/html; charset=cp1251

У вас сервер говорит, что отдает в cp1251, вот браузер и путается.

Comment: Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно на сервере по стандарту стоит кодировка cp1251.

Можно попробовать это решить создав файл .htaccess из содержимым

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вставить в самое начало файла это:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: я подпишусь под этим комментарием просто потому, что он избавляет от необходимости настраивать сервер при переносе